# R bar chart: Some values are not represented in stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm tinkering nor for hours on this particular problem, where some random values are not represented for some reason in my stacked bar chart.

I checked for irregularities as well as format - but couldn't find any explanation on why this problem appears...

My data looks as following

```
    year   A P    B P     A R   B R
1  2005 443.0  268.4 10952.1 289.9
2  2006 216.5   76.6 18403.4 123.9
3  2007 181.4  232.5  1739.9 317.4
4  2008 148.5   50.0   284.9 226.8
5  2009 449.6  136.9   459.2  70.8
6  2010 190.6  383.7   638.2 147.6
7  2011 151.0  307.0  1133.0 177.4
8  2012  22.5  199.5    52.8  71.0
9  2013 956.0  393.8   637.6  47.1
10 2014 892.0  189.5   899.8  50.7
11 2015 340.8  242.4   782.4  40.6
12 2016 187.8 1262.2  3272.0 121.5
```

I then "melted" the data and grouped it:

```
m_ML <- melt(ML, id = "year")
m_ML$groups <- stri_extract_last_words(m_ML$variable)
```

And created a nice looking plot (except for the missing data):

```
MLT <- ggplot(m_ML, aes(x= year, y= value, group= groups, fill= variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
        theme_economist() + scale_colour_economist() + 
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5000))
```

The outcome was then this:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKDAZ.jpg)

As you can see, the plot seems to work, except for missing data for some reason although data is here and should be shown as well. (e.g. the value "A R" missing in 2007, 2010,2011, 2012 and 2016)

Trying to scale it down, so that also the lowest values have to be shown doesn't work as well.

I would be extremely glad if some could educate me on this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are plotting the bars over each other. The missing bars are behind the others.

Behold:

```
ggplot(m_ML, aes(x= factor(year), y= value, group= groups, fill= variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", col = 1, alpha = 0.2) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5000))
```

[image]

One solution is stacking:

```
ggplot(m_ML, aes(x= groups, y= value, group= groups, fill= variable)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~year, switch = 'x') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5000)) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or just simpler grouping:

```
ggplot(m_ML, aes(x= factor(year), y= value, fill= variable)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5000))
```

[image]

Comment: If I'd tell you I love you, it would be a severe understatement! Thank you a thousand times! Could you maybe explain to me why "stacking" is not working as I assumed it would? (i.e. Values of the same group will be just stacked on top of each other) Cheers!

Comment: @Somedude, in case it wasn't clear, it's the `position = "dodge"` argument that makes the bars appear side by side.

Comment: Yes, setting `position` to dodge turns off the stacking. You can't do both at the same time, i.e. you can't have dodged stacks.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder how I could have missed that. Thank you again for your help!